# Device VID and PID to pass into function

Tags: visual-c++, pid

I am trying to use the following function:

```
PCHAR pVID_PID="vid_04D8&pid_fc5f";
DWORD n= MPUSBGetDeviceCount(pVID_PID);
```

It is imported from [mpusbapi.h](http://www.excamera.com/files/xess-python/xula/xstools/MCHPFSUSB/Pc/Mpusbapi/Dll/Borland_C/mpusbapi.h), where it is defined as such:

```
DWORD (*MPUSBGetDeviceCount)(PCHAR pVID_PID);
```

I was wondering where I can find my USB device's VID&PID information. The one I am using doesn't seem to be working because `cout<<n` ouputs `0`! Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will normally find them in the driver '.inf' files associated with the device you are using.